# How could I get the exact range value when I select a portion in amcharts?

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm  working on an angular application and I'm using the chart library amcharts. I want to make a selection and get the range of the selected portion. here is the code:

```
    this.chart.cursor.behavior = "selectX";
    this.chart.cursor.events.on("selectended", function(ev) {
      var range = ev.target.xRange;
      var axis = ev.target.chart.xAxes.getIndex(0);
      var from = (axis.getPositionLabel(axis.toAxisPosition(range.start)));
      var to = (axis.getPositionLabel(axis.toAxisPosition(range.end)));
      alert("Selected from " + from + " to " + to);
    });
```

the to and from variable are only getting the day not the full date.
ps: xaxis is a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the axis' [`positionToDate`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#positionToDate_method) method to get the exact Date object value from where the range is drawn:

```
this.chart.cursor.behavior = "selectX";
this.chart.cursor.events.on("selectended", function(ev) {
  var range = ev.target.xRange;
  var axis = ev.target.chart.xAxes.getIndex(0);
  var from = (axis.positionToDate(axis.toAxisPosition(range.start)));
  var to = (axis.positionToDate(axis.toAxisPosition(range.end)));
  alert("Selected from " + from + " to " + to);
});
```